# problem with 2 button layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two buttons (buy and share) in my layout and I want them to occupy equal space. However, "share" button is occupying much more space than "buy" button. Can any one kindly point out my mistake ? Thanks.

```
            <Button
            android:id="@+id/shareButton"
            android:text="Share"
            android:background="@drawable/ebutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50px"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
            android:paddingRight="10dip"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            >
            </Button>

            <Button
            android:id="@+id/buyButton"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/shareButton"
            android:text="Buy"
            android:background="@drawable/ebutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50px"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
            android:paddingRight="10dip"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            >
            </Button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put both buttons in a LinearLayout and define a `weightSum` of 2 for the LinearLayout, then set the `weight` of each button to 1 and the two views will be scaled to occupy half of the parent.

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="2">  
        <Button android:id="@+id/buyBtn" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Buy"/>

        <Button android:id="@+id/shareBtn" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Share"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is a really powerful layout technique as you can define a what fraction of a parent a view should occupy.  For example if you wanted 3 buttons with the first occupying half the screen and the other two occupying a quarter you could set the parent `weightSum` to 4, and the `weight` of the first to 2 and the `weight` of the other two buttons to 1.